# Nginx $_GET parameter is empty

Tags: php, nginx

Firstly sorry if this is a double post, i've searched and saw there are many posts on this subject here on stackoverflow, but they all say the same thing, add $args or $query_strings to the index.php and it should work, but i have done that and it does not, it shows the $_GET parameter to be empty.

Here is the config file for the domain

```
server {    
    listen      *:80;
    listen      *:443 ssl http2;
    server_name site.ro www.site.ro;
    # The Document Root
    root        /home/razvypp/www/site.ro;

    error_log   /usr/local/apps/nginx/var/log/site.ro.err;
    access_log  /usr/local/apps/nginx/var/log/site.ro.log main;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}


    ssl_certificate             /etc/ssl/cert/site.ro.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key         /etc/ssl/private/site.ro.key;
    ssl_dhparam                 /etc/ssl/private/dhparam.pem;



    location = /favicon.ico {
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
            allow all;
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
    }



    include     /usr/local/apps/nginx/etc/conf.d/common;
}
```

Comment: I think you are missing a location block, that tells nginx how to use php with fastcgi_params. But that's a google search. E.g. https://askubuntu.com/questions/134666/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-enable-php-on-nginx

Comment: What's the status of the question? Did the answer given (so far) solve the question? If it did, you should mark it off as solved by accepting the answer, otherwise everyone will think that your question is still open. You can also do the same for any of your past questions that were resolved.

Comment: It did not solve my problem, i had to add rules in php to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried changing the parameter.

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html /index.php?$args;
}
```

It should work after adding /index.html to your existing code..

Comment: ok, a new update, seems like the following works, for example http://example.com/file.php?param=1 but, a pretty url pages with parameter like http://example.com/my-custom-page/?param=1 does not work

Comment: @Pepelea Razvan lonut There are several workarounds using regex (RewriteRule ^/logs/(\d+)$ /dir1/dir2/logs?page=$1), but I resolved this by adding another   // location /my-custom-page {....  block to my configuration file and then reload nginx.